# $Key is not working to retrieve specific id of list of firebase objects

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to render specific product form my firebase product list.

I am unable to find key in my firebase list:-

```html
<tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let p of products$ | async">
            <td>{{p.title}}</td>
            <td>{{p.price}}</td>
            <td>
                <a [routerLink]="['/admin/products/',p.$key]">Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

I my browser redirects me to an undefined object:

```
http://localhost:4200/admin/products/undefined
```

Here post my Firebase list:

[Firebase List of Products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EP7dm.png)

Also I faced same problem with my category list also:-

here the code I have used :-

```html
 <div class="form-group">
                <label for="category">Category</label>
                <select #category="ngModel" ngModel name="category" id="category" type="text" class="form-control" required>
                  <option value=""></option>
                  <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.$Key" >
                    {{ c.name }}
                  </option>
                </select>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="category.touched && category.invalid">
                  Category is required.
                </div>
              </div>  ....
              
              .....
              
   export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {

  categories$;

  constructor(private router: Router,
    categoryService: CategoryService,
    private productService: ProductService) {

    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();
  }

  save(product) {
   this.productService.create(product);
   console.log(product)
  //  this.router.navigate(['admin/products'])
   }
```

If I look into consolelog, it shows Category Undefined:-
[Category is undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOEhR.png)

So both when I create the product using category,I am unable to find Category Key,even though I have selected my category from drop down list.

So, Please help me this regards.

Comment: From your firebase snapshot, I didn't see any `$key` field in the product object. So therefore `p.$key` will be `undefined`. You should add a field to your product object call `$key`.

Comment: -LQU8HompwKex4icbWdO,-LQUTngLsCaVC3KUF-yn these are the unique id or key.As per my understanding when you create an object these keys are automatically created.Am I right?.If I want to access that key or id how can I do that.I have checked with previous post as well and I noticed $key is working well for them but in my case somehow it is not working.So, please help me in this regards.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer after research, hope it works for you as well.

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="category">Category</label>
    <select ngModel name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
        <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.key">
            {{c.payload.val().name}}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

```js
export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {

  categories$;  

  constructor(categoryService: CategoryService, private productService:ProductService) {

    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories().snapshotChanges();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I tried to comment earlier, What I usually do is create a field under each item to hold my key. That way I don't need to be going through the hoops of getting the $key in the front end.
 So if you had a field under  each product as so, `$key: 'Key_1Ceuejd`.

Then your *ngFor would have worked just perfectly with the `p.$key`.

That said, with what you have, you will need to do 2 *ngFor's to achieve your result.

First, set a variable `objectKeys` in your component class to get the keys.

Then in your template, do the following:

```
   <ng-container *ngFor='let key of objectKeys(products)'>
     <h2>key: {{key}}</h2>
     <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor='let p of products[key]'>
            <td>{{p.title}}</td>
            <td>{{p.price}}</td>
            <td>
                <a routerLink="'/admin/products/{{key}}">Edit {{key}}</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
<ng-container>
```

## Example 2 Firebase Data

This example with firebase data, you won't need two *ngFors, rather you get the product details, by product key `firebaseData[key]`. I guess this is what you are looking for.

```
<ng-container *ngFor='let key of firebaseObjectKeys(firebaseData)'>
     <h2>key: {{key}}</h2>
     <tbody>
       {{firebaseData[key] | json}}
        <tr *ngIf='firebaseData[key]'>
            <td><h3>{{firebaseData[key].slang}}</h3></td>
            <td>{{firebaseData[key].slangDefine}}</td>
            <td>
                <a routerLink="'/admin/products/{{key}}">Edit {{key}}</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</ng-container>
```

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-umpqyh